# Sharepoint Project Server Integration

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

Client wants a master schedule integrated into an existing sharepoint site. Would project server be the best way to go about this? SharePoint server 2010.

Comment: Hi Jay, welcome to the SharePoint StackExchange community! Could you provide some more details about your scenario, like what they are using to manage the schedule now and what kind of site they want it integrated with?

Answer (score 1):

If by master schedule you actually think "global resource calendar(-s)" - than yes, Project Server integration with SharePoint 2010 could help you achieve that, but in the context of managing projects - you shouldn't install & configure it just for the "global calendar" - rather use Exchange calendars.

If on the other hand you only need to simulate a global calendar, SharePoint could allow you to do so in many ways, e.g. calendar overlays (up to 10 calendars), global calendars with custom web parts, etc.